# how does a linker functions?

Tags: c, header

In static linking, how does the linker knows which library file to link the user's compiled object code against? I mean the header only contains the function protoytpes that may be used in the source code, not the library file name.. isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a C/C++ compiler find the definitions of prototypes in header files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368121/how-does-a-c-c-compiler-find-the-definitions-of-prototypes-in-header-files)

Comment: the link you mentioned does not answer the core question.. it only matches the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why you provide the linker with a list of libraries to link against!

e.g. for GCC, you might do something like:

```
gcc my_prog.o -lm -lpthread -o my_prog
```

Here, the `-l` flag is used to tell the linker to link against `libm` and `libpthread`.

Comment: While working in the IDE I don't explicitly provide the list of libraries.. I just press the build button. In such case, how the linker would choose the libraries to link against?

Comment: @Saurabh: the IDE calls the linker with the appropriate arguments. The linker doesn't "choose" anything.

Answer (score 1):

It gets a list of libraries from the command line.  The specifics will depend on the OS and the compiler.